# Can not read from the text file specified in c#.net

Tags: c#, .net, console-application, streamreader, streamwriter

I'm trying to read a text file in my `C#` console application, however it doesn't read from the text file specified in c#.net, how can I fix it?

My code:

```
string docPath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments);
if (File.Exists(docPath))
{
   string text = File.ReadAllText("token.txt");
   Console.WriteLine(text);
}
else
{
   Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Magenta;
   Console.WriteLine("Enter your token:");
   string token = Console.ReadLine();

   using (StreamWriter outputFile = new StreamWriter(Path.Combine(docPath, "token.txt")))
   {
      outputFile.Write(token);
   }
}
```

Instead of checking the contents of `token.txt` in the user documents, it just prompts the user to enter their token every time, which would get very annoying for the user.

What should I do to fix this?

Comment: Have you tried debugging?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem here is that your docPath variable doesn't hold the path to a single file, but instead the path of a folder. (C:\{User}\Documents)

So the File.Exists check will always fail, because you're targeting the folder.
Try combining your docPath with the actual file name and it should work.

Comment: I've tried ```string docPath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments("token.txt"));```
However it just throws an error. What should i use to include the txt file in the path?

Comment: You can use Path.Combine(docPath, "fileName") to get the path of your file.